# Error When trying to Baseline Prisma Database - Need to keep All of the Data

Tags: node.js, next.js, prisma

I am having trouble with my Prisma database because my LOCAL migration directory no longer matches the migration history inside _prisma_migrations table.

In order to fix it, I was trying to follow instructions for [Baseline your database](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/migrate/developing-with-prisma-migrate/baselining), but it seems that someone else before me has done that in the past (i.e., `0_init/migrations.sql` already exists, so I tried creating a new one `1_init/migrations.sql`)

This did not turn out well, because now I have `1_init` migration that has been marked as "**applied**" by executing command

`npx prisma migrate resolve --applied 1_init`

but could not actually apply it with

`npx prisma migrate dev`

due to the following error:

```
Error: P3006

Migration `1_init` failed to apply cleanly to the shadow database. 
Error:
db error: ERROR: type "TeamRole" already exists
   0: schema_core::state::DevDiagnostic
             at schema-engine/core/src/state.rs:266
```

My questions is, how do I fix this? Do I:

- Unmark 1_init migration as "no longer applied"? If so, how do I do that?
- Do I manually delete _prisma_migrations history and then try to apply 1_init migration

**NOTE**: Keep in mind that I do not want to lose my data